# How can i pass the value of a radio button with an id coming from db to a textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

> Hi, I wanted to pass the value of a radio button to a textbox upon selection of the radio button using  jquery and php.  The radio button is fetched according to the number
>   of row from my database. So I am assigning the row id, to be the id of
>   my radio button. I have tried the following code but no luck.  Please
>   tell me what I'm missing. Thanks in advance!

//my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#option<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>").click(

function(){
    var get = $("#option<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>").val();
    document.getElementById('DepartTime').value=get;



)


</script>
```

//on my php page , i have this

```
echo"<tr>";
  echo"<td><input type='radio'  id='option".$row['ID']."' name='departures' value='".$row['ID'].",".$row['Departure']."'></td>";
```

//then my textbox

```
<td><input type="text" id="DepartTime" name="DepartureTime" /></td>
```

Comment: "I am assigning the row id, to be the id of my radio button." it is not clear how do you do it. Do you dynamically generate the Javascript code in PHP?

Comment: No, I'm fetching the rows from my db and put the values inside an option button. so that every row is an option that i can choose. I hope I make it clear a little bit.. thanks PA

Comment: then on my javascript I'm trying to handle the click event of the radio buttons. that as I select the radio buttons it's corresponding value will appear on the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.click()` function is not getting invoked. For that you need to put it inside a self-invoking anonymous function or `.ready()` method :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Here goes your code
});
```

which is equivalent to calling :

```
$(function() {
    // Here goes your code
});
```

[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Also, you were missing a `}` in the last.

So, here is the correct code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $("#option<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>").click(function(){
        var get = $("#option<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>").val();
        document.getElementById('DepartTime').value=get;
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..I tried your suggestion but still not working.

Comment: Im not getting any error, but as I select through my radio buttons, no value is being reflected on my textbox.

Comment: Have you checked the values of `$row['ID']` and `$row['Departure']` ?

Comment: if I run it.. the id of the options will be like this "option1" "option2" "option3" and their value is something like this "1,8:30:00" but I'm not getting it reflected on my textbox..  - thanks Nikhil

Comment: the values I'm getting are Ok, it's just that it doesn't reflect on the textbox.